# Android jackson json: Support two data types within one @JsonProperty

Tags: android, json, kotlin, jackson, json-deserialization

I have modified my solution to the following code and still having problems.  Can anyone advise me on what I'm missing? Your help is greatly appreciated.

I have been searching here for the past few days and have tried different solutions, none of which have worked for me, so I decided to sign up and ask the question myself.

Here's what's going on:
A json property in my project could have two data types based on the api version.  It could either be a String or one key-value pair.
How will I be able to allow my @JsonProperty("field_with_two_possible_types") to have two possible types and parse them correctly?

Here's what my main data class looks like:

```
@PaperParcel
data class DataClass(

        @JsonProperty(“field_with_two_possible_types”)
        val symptomTime: FieldPOJO? = null,) : PaperParcelable {
    companion object {
        @JvmField
        val CREATOR = PaperParcelDataClass.CREATOR
    }
}

POJO Class

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type.id")
@JsonSubTypes(
JsonSubTypes.Type(name = “string_value”, value = String::class),
JsonSubTypes.Type(name = “object_value”, value = FieldSubPOJO::class))

class FieldPOJO() : Parcelable {

    var value1: String? = null

    var value2: FieldSubPOJO? = null

    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this() {
        value1 = parcel.readString()
        value2 = parcel.readParcelable(FieldSubPOJO::class.java.classLoader)
    }

    override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        parcel.writeString(value1)
        parcel.writeParcelable(va;ie2, flags)
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<FieldPOJO> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): FieldPOJO {
            return FieldPOJO(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<FieldPOJO?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you check here: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization

Comment: @seyedJafari Thanks for forwarding this. I had seen similar stuff. I looked into it in detail and applied as much as I could to my classes. I've edited the post to show how my classes look like right now. I'm getting the following exception: 
`Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of [simple type, class com.example.android.FieldPOJO]: missing type id property 'type.id' (for POJO property 'field_with_two_possible_types')`
Can you please help me out?

Comment: Could I be missing a TypeResolver class, to be added to either the FieldPOJO or DataClass?
`@JsonTypeResolver(NestedTypeResolver.class)`

Comment: In the `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation, I have tried using `@class`, `type`, and some other ones for the `property` parameter, and they have failed, as well.

Comment: just one thing out of curiosity why don't you use 2 totally separate base classes?

Comment: I do have two separate base classes. DataClass and FieldPOJO are two separate classes. I have just copied and pasted them together here.  Do you have any idea why I'm getting the above exception?